# Nested loops in PHP extremely slow

Tags: php, loops

I have 6 nested loops in a PHP program, however, the calculation time for the script is extremely slow. I would like to ask if there is a better way of implementing the 6 loops and increasing computation time, even if it means switching to another language. The nature of the algorithm I'm implementing requires iteration, so I don't know how I can better implement it.

Here's the code.

```
<?php
$time1 = microtime(true);
$res = 16;
$imageres = 128;
for($x=0;$x<$imageres;++$x){
    for($y=0;$y<$imageres;++$y){ 
        $pixels[$x][$y]=1;  
    }};
$quantizermatrix = 1;
$scalingcoefficient = 1/($res/2);
for($currentimagex=0;$currentimagex<($res*($imageres/$res-1)+1);$currentimagex = $currentimagex +$res){
    for($currentimagey=0;$currentimagey<($res*($imageres/$res-1)+1);$currentimagey = $currentimagey +$res){
        for($u=0;$u<$res;++$u){
            for($v=0;$v<$res;++$v){   
                for($x=0;$x<$res;++$x){
                    for($y=0;$y<$res;++$y){
                        if($u == 0) {$a = 1/(sqrt(2));} else{$a = 1;};
                        if($v == 0){$b = 1/(sqrt(2));}else{$b = 1;};
                        $xes[$y] = $pixels[$x+$currentimagex][$y+$currentimagey]*cos((M_PI/$res)*($x+0.5)*$u)*cos( M_PI/$res*($y+0.5)*$v);
                    }
                    $xes1[$x] = array_sum($xes);
                }
                $xes2= array_sum($xes1)*$scalingcoefficient*$a*$b;
                $dctarray[$u+$currentimagex][$v+$currentimagey] = round($xes2/$quantizermatrix)*$quantizermatrix;
            }}}};
foreach($dctarray as $dct){
    foreach($dct as $dc){
        echo $dc." ";
    }
    echo "<br>";}
$time2 = microtime(true);echo 'script execution time: ' . ($time2 - $time1);
?>
```

I've removed a large portion of the code that's irrelevant, since this is the section of the code that's problematic

Essentially the code iterates through every pixel in a PNG image and outputs a computed matrix (2d array). This code takes around 2 seconds for a 128x128 image. This makes this program impractical for normal images greater than 128x128

Comment: I'd say 2 seconds is pretty good for 4.4 trillion iterations. Have you tried looking at a library like `Imagick` to see if one of its many functions supports your needs?

Comment: How did you get that number? There's nowhere nearly that many calculations being done in a 128x128 matrix

Comment: He multiplied six numbers. You are wrong with building such deep cycles. Depth 3 is enough.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the code... I assumed `$res` was `128` - hence `128^6`. It's only 16.7 million iterations...

Answer (score 0):

There is a function available in `Imagick` library

```
Imagick::exportImagePixels
```

Refer the below link it might help you out
    http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.exportimagepixels.php

Comment: Putting the image into an array is not the slow part. That happens fairly fast. I need to be able to calculate the 2D discrete cosine transform of the image, and that requires the 6 loops (unless there's a library for it with custom block sizes and quantization tables)

Comment: yes seems there is no library available for 2d DCT 
Go for Matlab it has lot more scopes for 2d DCT.